# How to read a configuration file, or create one if it's missing

Tags: c, file, conditional-statements, fopen, race-condition

How do you make a file, but only if it doesn't already exist? Like.. I want to read a text file, but if it doesn't exist, I want to create one with some default text.

I can create the file with the default text easy enough. And I can append or overwrite it if it already exists.

But if it already contains some text, I want to READ FROM it. Not WRITE TO it. Like you might do with a dot file or configuration file, to set a default configuration in the event the file is missing.

This is quite simple with Python, but I'm trying to make the transition to C, and It's more challenging than I'd anticipated.

---

So my function basically looks something like this so far. The text is just a placeholder for whatever the real text might be.

```
main() {
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("./filename.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "some default text\n");
    fclose(fp);
}
```

---

So just to clarify: If `./file.txt` already exists, it shouldn't be written to. It should be read from.

When I say "read from", it could be printed to `stdout`, or stored in an array for instance, but that's probably beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You know how to read an existing file. Try to do it. If it fails, create a new file.

Comment: Hint: checking return values of your file operations is mandatory! They tell you what to do.

Comment: There is race-condition tag in the question. Some answers seems to allow opening a file for writing for several processes at the same time.

Comment: @SKi that's alright, I'm happy for any contributions. Even if an answer's not perfect, I can generally still learn something useful from it. I take them all with a grain of salt anyway. I knew it was inevitable the race condition would be a point of contention, so the tag seemed appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

Considering your example there are two main mistakes:

1. You don't check the result of `fopen` thus you don't know whether your file has been successfully opened (here is the key to the answer).
2. `printf` function prints directrly to `stdout` and you have to use `fprintf` one for printing to your configuration file.

I propose the following: try to `fopen` your configuration file (e.g. `./filename.txt`) for `r` and check the result of this call. Upon successful completion `fopen` return a `FILE` pointer to your *existing* configuration file. If the file doesn't exist `fopen` returns `NULL` and errno is set to `ENOENT`. In this case you can create a new configuration file and write a default config into it.

Please see `man 3` section for the corresponding docs.

**UPD**:

Here is PoC for the proposal

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen(".rc", "r");
    if (!fp)
        switch (errno) {
            case ENOENT:
                fprintf(stderr, "No config found, creating the default one\n");
                fp = fopen(".rc", "w");
                if (!fp) {
                    perror("Failed to create default config: ");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
                /* write default config here */
                break;
            default:
                perror("Failed to open existing config: ");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

    /* read existing config here */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: 1. I wasn't aware I could do that, or how to do it, but it sounds good. Like `try`, `except` in python.
2. Sorry, `printf` was a typo, it was meant to be `fprintf` like you say, I fixed it up in the question. Maybe I should have left it for posterity, I'm not sure.

Comment: This is somewhat like `try`-`except`, *except* that technically it's totally not. URW ;)

Comment: Cool. I think I understand. So what does the code look like in context? This seems like a better answer than the other, but it's much easier to understand when I can see the code and visualize how it pieces together. I mean, it probably makes a lot of sense to people who are already familiar with it. But I'm still finding my feet. Is it like: `if (fp == NULL) { fp ->`.. something or other?

Comment: I've updated my answer as you both suggested and removed the one below, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [stat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) before opening your file. If the stat is successful then the file exists, if it is not, check for ENOENT in errno.

## Example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    struct stat file_infos;
    char file_path[] = "/whatever"
    if (stat(file_path, &file_infos) != 0)
    {
        if (errno == ENOENT)
        {
            // Do whatever when the file wasn't found
        }
        else
        {
            // Error accessing the file, check the errno for more infos
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // File exists, do whatever you like with it.
    }
}
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: Now you have to check two API call results, first `stat` then `fopen`, why not directly try to open the file. What is the advantage of calling stat first?

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion. I appreciate the example.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff, there is none, just another approach.